# JQuery - remove a class child elements with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="blackSheep"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

How do I remove all elements with className "child" that only are the ones inside "parent"-div

Result I want is this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="blackSheep"></div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to select the elements? Or how to remove them? Both are very simple tasks that you'd learn in a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: You can use this code: `$('.parent .child').remove();`. `.child1` is a child of `.parent`.

Comment: Someone actually thinks this question shows research effort?

Answer (score 9):

Something like this

```js
$('.parent').find('.child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="blackSheep">blackSheep</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<div class="child">child Outside</div>
<div class="child">child Outside</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use `$("div.parent > div.child").remove();`

This will select all div's with class child that are direct children of div's with class parent and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.parent .child').remove();
```