# How to filter and remove child nodes from queried HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would remove all the childNode which has the class of `hidePost`. In an other method I toggle `hidePost` like this:

```
p.toggleClass("hidePost");
```

I wrote these lines, but is is syntactical not valid:

```
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post")[0]
emailTemplate.find('.hidePost').each(function(i, obj) {
    emailTemplate.remove(obj)
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: emailTemplate.find is not a function

---

I tried also this, but raise the same error:

```
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post")[0].outerHTML
emailTemplate.find('.hidePost').remove();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - remove a class child elements with certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745117/jquery-remove-a-class-child-elements-with-certain-class)

Comment: In jQuery try: `$(".class").removeClass("class");`, In native JavaScript: try `document.querySelector(".class").removeClass("class");`.

Comment: Why `[0]` after the selector ?

Comment: Kevin: he wants to remove the full node not only the class

Comment: `emailTemplate.find is not a function`, Because `[0]` gets the underlying dom element which doesnt have a find method. You would need to rewrap it into a jQuery object to get the `find` method, eg `$(emailTemplate)`. Or just use `.eq(0)` so you get a jQuey object, eg `$("#email-post").eq(0)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Having to use  `.eq(0)` would mean that he has more than one  element with id `#email-post`  . Which would be a NO NO :) Hence my above comment : ' Why [0] after the selector ? "

Comment: @Elikill58, I checked the answer with 4 vote, but raise the same error, case I appended to the question

Comment: In the first example, remove the `[0]` and it should work

Comment: Yes, or with something like `$('#email-post').find('.hidePost').remove();`

Comment: @Elikill58 that will remove the element itself, not the children

Comment: _"but raise the same error:"_ , you need to look up what those properties/methods are returning. That is the second time you have thought something was giving you a jQuery object and was giving you something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example will work if you remove `[0]`, which gets the HTML element, which does not have a `.find` method.

```js
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post");
emailTemplate.find('.hidePost').each(function(i, obj) {
    emailTemplate.remove(obj)
});
```

I would also recommend a second approach to removing an element's set of children by using the following:

```js
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post")
  .find('.hidePost')
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="email-post">
  <div class="hidePost">child to be removed</div>
  <div class="hidePost">child to be removed</div>
  <div class="hidePost">child to be removed</div>
  <div>A child not removed</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such as suggest in comment, this works:

```js
$('#email-post').find('.hidePost').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it also if you need an index or the obj.

```js
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post").find('.hidePost');
emailTemplate.each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="email-post">
  <p class="hidePost">First</p>
  <p class="hidePost">Second</p>
  <p class="hidePost">Third</p>
  <p class="hidePost">Fourth</p>
  <p class="anotherClass">Fifth</p>
</div>
```